# how to update record and same record create in other table in django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i have 2 model one is Tempdriver and other one is Hiring,
i am  register new customer in Tempdriver table, i need when i edit tempdriver record and status
is (accept) and when i save this record then need to same record create on hiring table with matching column with status=(Applied on app) rest column should be null in hiring table

**models.py**

```
class Tempdriver(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True,null=True, blank=True)
    alternate_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    status = EnumField(choices=['Accept','Reject','Hold'], null=True)

class Hiring(BaseModel):

    STATUS_CHOICES = (('', 'Type...'),
                      ('HR Interview Pass', 'HR Interview Pass'),
                      ('HR Interview Fail', 'HR Interview Fail'),
                      ('Allocation Completed', 'Allocation Completed'),
                      ('Applied on app','Applied on app')
                      )

    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True,null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, models.CASCADE, verbose_name='City', null=True, blank=True)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 255,choices=STATUS_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class TempDriverForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
        model= Tempdriver
        fields='__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
def edit_temp_driver(request,id=0):
    tempdr=Tempdriver.objects.get(pk=id)
    form= TempDriverForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=tempdr)
    if form.is_valid():
        edit = form.save(commit=False)
        edit.save()
        messages.success(request,'Driver data updated successfully!')
        return redirect('/fleet/tempdr')    
    return render(request, 'hiringprocess/edit_tempdriver.html', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me to ask, why you use `BaseModel` instead of `models.Model' ?(just for my information, i just wanted to ask in a comment, but i'm not permmited)

If i understand your question correctly, your function `edit_temp_driver` would be something like this:

```
def create_hiring_object(form):
    try:
        obj = Hiring()
        obj.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        obj.mobile = form.cleaned_data['mobile']
        obj.status = obj.STATUS_CHOICES[4]
        obj.save()
    except Exception as err:
        # return error
        return err

def edit_temp_driver(request,id=0):
    tempdr=Tempdriver.objects.get(pk=id)
    form= TempDriverForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=tempdr)
    if form.is_valid():
        edit = form.save(commit=False)
        # call to create hiring 
        create_hiring_object(form)
        edit.save()
        messages.success(request,'Driver data updated successfully!')
        return redirect('/fleet/tempdr')    
    return render(request, 'hiringprocess/edit_tempdriver.html', {'form':form})
```